# Compile issue with FStar and mono

Tags: f#, mono, fstar

I'm trying to compile FStar language on latest Ubuntu and mono. [GitHub repo](https://github.com/FStarLang/FStar/blob/master/INSTALL) provides some build instruction, but it doesn't work for me. After

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete fsharp
mozroots --import --sync
source setenv.sh 
make -C src
```

I'm get this error message:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `../bin/jsbackend.dll', needed by `../bin/fstar.exe'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `/home/alex/FStar/src'
```

Full log available [here](http://pastebin.com/ZJqbx5E0).

How can I build FStar language on mono?

Comment: I would suggest filing an issue on the github page

Answer (score 2):

Someone created a bug report and it now builds on Ubuntu out of the box.

Even though it's not mentioned in the INSTALL instructions, it is also necessary to set up Z3 from http://z3.codeplex.com/releases/view/101911.